# Javascript: exporting objects initialized asynchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, initialization, export

Hello and apologies for the newbie question! ;)

To respect an interface already in use by my colleagues I need to export a method like this:

```
let pool;   // a pool of connections to a DB
// ...
module.exports = {
  query: (text, params) => pool.query(text, params),
}
```

This was no problem when pool was initialized synchronously, but then I needed to load some configuration from DB, so I need to call something like

```
// ...
config=await configLoader.loadConfigFromDB("myService");
// ...
pool  = new Pool(config);
// ...
```

So my code looks something like:

```
// ...
let pool;

(async function(){ 
    config=await configLoader.loadConfigFromDB("myService");
    // ...
    pool  = new Pool(config);
    // ...
  })();

module.exports = {
  query: (text, params) => pool.query(text, params),
}
```

Needless to say, due to timing issues *pool* is often undefined. I faced similar issues in the past and solved them always in different ways, none of them applicable this time: is there any best practice to satisfy my need and in general to export something which needs to be initialized asynchronously? And which doesn't require the users change their way of using *query*.
In particular I'm using Node.js, but I'd like to learn a general solution.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Store the return of the IIFE function, and then modify your query to await this.

Comment: `let pool = (async function () { ... return pool; })();`then use the promise whenever you want to run a query: `pool.then(pool => pool.query(...))`

Comment: Thank you very much to everyone, also for pointing me to the other post, you all fixed my issues :)